# Convert columns to rows in pairs using Informatica powercenter or SQL

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter, denormalized

I have a requirement where I have to track changes on a column and display changed and new value

I have a source file with employee attributes. I did a lookup on employee table and returned employee attributes on which I am tracking changes. I created a flag where I am comparing columns from source and look. I also have a router to filter out update_flag='Y'

employee_id,name,old_department_id,new_department_id,old_salary,new_salary

1,SAM,10,20,100,200

to

employee_id,employee_attribute,old_value,new_value

1,SAM,department_id,10,20

1,SAM,salary,100,200

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Router with an output for each record you want to create. The Router can output multiple records for a single input record.

```
Group1 : old_department_id != new_department_id
Group2 : old_salary != new_salary
```

After the Router you use Expressions to build the record values you want like adding the column `employee_attribute`. Then you combine the outputs of each Expression with a Union.